# Codename One plugin uninstalled / reinstalled, still bug with a skin

Tags: codenameone

A user has tried to install a new skin for the simulator and things did not work, see screenshot:

[image]

He uninstalled / reinstalled the CodenameOne plugin but the preview remains bugged as indicated on the screenshot above. Is there some hidden config files he should delete elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skins are installed in this directory: **C:\Users\UserName\.codenameone**, some of them might have been corrupted during addition.

You can try removing all before re-installing CN1 plugin to see if it solves the problem. Particularly the skins with recent **Date modified**.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you pick a corrupt skin file, we made several attempts at fixing it which apparently still didn't resolve the issue.

To workaround it in Windows launch the `resedit` tool and type into find: "JavaSEPort".

Delete everything you find in that search and it should restore you to the default state.